# multiplying a float, getting wrong answer (php)

Tags: php, floating-point, number-formatting

I have a float that is return data from a cURL call, that I would like multiply by 0.25% (a fee) and then sum (add fee to subtotal)

code:

```
var_dump(var_dump($obook['Bid']);
echo number_format(($obook['Bid'] *= 0.0025) + $obook['Bid'], 8););
```

output:

```
float(0.01191616)
0.00005958
```

I am able to get the percentage amount, but not add it to the subtotal.

How to I calculate a fee and sum, to a float?

i.e.  0.01191616 * 0.0025 = $fee

$fee +  0.01191616  = $new_grand_total

UPDATE:
This is not correct:

```
$commis = $obook['Bid'] *= 0.0025;
var_dump(number_format($commis, 8));
```

output:

```
string(10) "0.00002976"
```

Comment: Why are you still using `*=` in the update? Do you still not understand the difference between `*` and `*=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$obook['Bid'] *= 0.0025
```

means to multiply the variable by `0.0025` and then put that result back in `$obook['Bid']`. Then when you add `$obook['Bid']` to it, you're just doubling that result.

In other words, your code is equivalent to:

```
$obook['Bid'] = $obook['Bid'] * 0.0025;
echo number_format(2 * $obook['Bid'], 8);
```

Because of this, you're losing the original value of `$obook['Bid']`, replacing it with just the fee, and then adding the fee to itself.

You should use `*`, not `*=`, if you don't want to update the variable.

```
$new_grand_total = $obook['Bid'] * 0.0025 + $obook['Bid'];
```

You can also use high school algebra to realize that `x * y + x` is equivalent to `x * (1+y)`, so you can do:

```
$new_grand_total = $obook['bid'] * 1.0025;
```

Comment: then it's spitting out bad math.  0.01190264 times 0.0025 plus 0.01190264 equals 0.01193239  on my calculator.

Comment: Where do you get `0.01190264` from? The original value is `0.01191616`. When you multiply that by `0.0025` you get `0.0000297904`, and when you double that the result is `0.00005958`.

Comment: @dooode Why are you adding `0.01190264` to it? Didn't you understand the main point of the answer, which is that you're adding the result of the multiplication, not the original value?

Comment: 0.01190264  is the value being spit out from cURL. the subtotal. What I need to add a fee to.  so 0.01190264  * .0025 = fee  (like what you have) and then add 0.01190264 back to that fee  so that user can see ALL the money he needs and not just the fee. a grand total.

Comment: oops, I meant  01191616  ,  paste error.  updated in question as well.

Comment: I've updated the answer, maybe it will clarify for you.

Answer (score 0):

do this instead:

```
$obook['bid'] *= 1.0025
```

Comment: what about summing it with the subtotal?  That gives only the fee amount.

Comment: it gives just the fee if you use `0.0025`.  I used `1.0025`

Comment: getting the fee is no problem. Getting the fee added back onto that subtotal "following the fee calculation" is where my problem is.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested?  Start with a nice easy number like `$obook['bid'] = 100`.  Then multiply it like I suggested: `$obook['bid'] *= 1.0025`.  You'll see that the new value is `100.25`.  You automatically get the `fee +  subtotal`

Comment: I know that math is incorrect.  .25%  of 0.01191616 equals  2.97904e-05  plus 0.01191616  equals 0.0119459504  on my calculator

Comment: Well that's the result you get when you do what I suggested. Here it is live: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9a5291f29ffbd97a5d435c5267639fd8d795c8c